# Htaccess Arabic url

Tags: .htaccess, arabic

I am trying to modify htaccess file.
I already have 3 language structures on my site (en / tr / ar).
htaccess is works fine for TR/EN , but I see the following error in arabic pages.

Image is below that you can see

[image]

https://image.ibb.co/cqHNTb/Untitled_1_copy.png

Comment: Guys I am waiting until morning I mean That I have to do until morning

Comment: Guys please help me